# xrandr clone monitor autodetect resolution

Tags: xorg, xrandr, multi-monitor

I want to write a script to clone my current desktop to another monitor, but I can't get the second monitors resolution to be set to the resolution of the primary monitor.

How can I automatically set the resolution of the second monitor to be the same as the first monitor?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is the output of your xrandr when both monitors are connected.  If it is for example something like this:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1400 x 1050, maximum 1400 x 1400
VGA disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS connected 1400x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 286mm x 214mm
   1400x1050      60.0*+   50.0  
[...]
```

Then you can use `sed` to get the resolution of your primary monitor (here LVDS) and set that to your secondary monitor (here VGA):

```
RESOLUTION=$(xrandr | sed -nr 's/LVDS connected ([0-9]+x[0-9]+).*/\1/p')
xrandr --output VGA --mode $RESOLUTION
```