# make xrandr output on two monitors

Tags: ubuntu, video, xrandr, multi-monitor, hdmi

My notebook has an *HDMI* connection to external monitor. I want have `xrandr` to pass parameters so that the image is displayed on both internal and external monitors, and when the external monitor is disconnected, the image continues to be displayed on the internal.

Currently I turn it off it manually:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --off --output HDMI1 --auto
```

And turn on:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --auto --output HDMI1 --auto
```

So I want to put `xrandr` command with correct parameters in `$HOME/.xinitrc`, so that video would go out on both monitors.

Comment: `man xrandr`, read up on `--same-as`.

Comment: @dirkt, thanks for pointing this option, but does `--same-as` go along with `--output` option? Can you give example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xrandr clone monitor autodetect resolution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190770/xrandr-clone-monitor-autodetect-resolution)

Comment: I'd say it is not a duplicate. The linked question is about setting the second display to a video mode with the same screen pixel area, but this is not required in this question.

Comment: @Mark, it is a "per-output" option, so it must come after an `--output` option. So `xrandr --output HDMI1 --same-as LVDS1` to make `HDMI1` show the same as `LVDS1`.